# Website animation only working correctly in Firefox

Tags: jquery

Somewhat new to this.

Working on a site that has many animations using jQuery.
[This is the site](http://pantsateria.com/linda/alphabetExperiment.html)

If you would take a minute to look at it in Firefox what you will see is exactly what I intended, but if you look at it in Chrome or Safari it does not work correctly (but displays the same strange "errors" in both - omitted animations & timing way off).

Stranger still, In IE (9) some of the words show up about 20px higher than intended, but animations do not.

Also, Chrome, Safari and IE show an image missing on left of screen, but there is nothing that should be there.

**Note**: HTML looks redundant because all id and classes that end with "L" are for a large screen media query - where animations would cover the larger monitor - that I did not include in this example)

PS: I have read that the onload function in JS can be quirky, but I have tried many ways to open the code, and they all display the same quirks.

Comment: I see the animations on Chrome for windows. As for the broken image, it's #dummyEvent, points to img/dummy.jpg . Did you perhaps intend to remove that?

Comment: For a good start try to make your site http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpantsateria.com%2Flinda%2FalphabetExperiment.html Html valid. There a lot of HTML errors on your site. Hope it helps;)

Comment: Thanks for advice. Fixed all html errors (but one) and Dummy event, but it still has the same exact problems in both Chrome and Safari. ("dummy event" was missing image - forgot to upload - it was an idea to delay animations in Chrome and Safari until images fully loaded (did not work).

Comment: Sorry, posted response prematurely. If you look at beginning of animation in Firefox or IE9 you will se a gondola with a skeleton appear from left of screen and go behind the slideshow, THEN a skeleton will drop from behind slideshow and an empty gondola will appear from the right side of the slideshow. If you watch the beginning in Chrome or Safari the skeleton drops before the 1st gondola (with skeleton) goes behind slidehow and the empty gondola never comes out. If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciateded. thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not intended for "help me find all the errors on my site" type question.  Please formulate a concise programming question and include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out problem. It was using %s in the js (chrome and safari did not like them)

Thanks